# Mapping Class property in CsvHelper

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I would like to know how to map class property when parsing a csv using CsvHelper. For example
my csv is like this

**Person**, John, 53

**Address**, 123 st, CA90045

and my models are like this

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int Age {get;set;}
  public Address Address {get;set;}
}

public class Address
{
  public string Street {get;set;}
  public string Zip {get;set;}      
}
```

Then how would I set Person.Address to values mapped in Address?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this really CSV? In a CSV file all the rows have the same columns. You cannot have two rows typed differently.

Comment: yes it is a csv     https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-multiple-record-types/

Comment: It looks like CsvHelper can do more than only classic CSV. The linked example shows how to map. What is not clear about this example? Just replace `Foo` and `Bar` by `Person` and `Address`.

Comment: public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

In this case Bar property remains null..

Answer (score 1):

Based on the example you linked to, you will have to do some extra processing, as CSV data stores only flat structures. Hierarchical data cannot be represented as in Json or XML.

Assuming that you have done the mapping part right and that an address immediately follows a person on the next CSV-line

```cs
var persons = new List<Person>();
Person person;
while (csv.Read())
{
    switch (csv.GetField(0))
    {
        case "Person":
            person = csv.GetRecord<Person>();
            persons.Add(person);
            break;
        case "Address":
            Address address = csv.GetRecord<Address>();
            person.Address = address;
            break;
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown record type.");
    }
}
```